# Can I receive Velodyne (VLP-16) data with a simple UDP transport program?

Tags: sockets, udp

The Velodyne manual states:

- The VLP-16 outputs two types of UDP Ethernet packets: Data Packets and Position Packets.
- The data packet is 1248 bytes long and is sent on port 2368.
- The data packet is then combined with status and header data in a UDP packet and transmitted over the Ethernet.

So, Can I receive vlp-16 data a simple UDP transport program?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket

Adress = ''
Port = 2368

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)


sock.bind((Adress, Port))

while True:
        data = sock.recv(1206)
        ...

sock.close()
```

That is a simple python program which can get data from VLP-16.

Comment: You may want to provide details of what this is actually doing.